# Targeting Application for Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have an application for which I am targeting compatibility for Windows 10 OS. I have accessed my .exe file using a software (Resource Tuner 2).

According to the link mentioned below, I have edited my .exe file to add the supported OS `<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>` in the manifest part.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx

In the same link it is mentioned to add some values (SXS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID, SXS_MANIFEST .. etc) to my sources. I have no idea where to add them for achieving my target.

The manifest section of the exe is mentioned below (after including Windows 10 support)

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" language="*" processorArchitecture="*" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
        <application>
            <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
            <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
            <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
            <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
            <!-- Added for Windows 10 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
        </application>
    </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

From the link it is suggested that I should add the below section to my sources. I am not sure where should I add it.

```
SXS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID=1
SXS_MANIFEST=foo.manifest
SXS_ASSEMBLY_NAME=Microsoft.Windows.Foo
SXS_ASSEMBLY_VERSION=1.0    
SXS_ASSEMBLY_LANGUAGE_INDEPENDENT=1
SXS_MANIFEST_IN_RESOURCES=1
```

Please help with your suggestions.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want to do. You do not even need a manifest or anything if you just want to run your .exe on Windows 10. If it is created with the Win32 API, you can run it on any Windows NT.

Comment: The article is fairly clunky and assumes you build your program with the rc.exe resource compiler, as is normally done in C or C++ projects.  Surely you are not or you'd recognize the pattern.  Not a problem, just pick hard-coded values.  The resource ID always needs to be 1 for an exe.  And just pick whatever name and version is appropriate for your app, they don't actually get used.

Comment: When I open the exe file using Resource tuner, I found various section namely **Icon, Menu, String Table, RC Data, Icon Group, Version, Manifest**. I edited the Manifest part to add the `<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>` and built the application. I printed the Major and Minor versions for the Windows 10 OS and I am getting it as 6 and 2 respectively. I believe If I can add the details to the sources (updated in the question), I can fix this issue. Problem is I dont know where I should add it.

Comment: @HansPassant, where should I add the Resoure ID, name and version. Do I need to create a file with these details and include it in the **RC Data** section? If yes, then with what extension I should save this file?

Comment: No.  "and built the application" looks like the fatal flaw.  That will undo whatever you did with a resource hacking tool.  Not telling us anything about the kind of language and its build tooling makes it pretty hard to help you.

Comment: The application is an installation wizard written with Inno setup (.iss). The whole application is built with maven. I found that the current code was not compatible with Windows 10 as it is returning the Version as 6.2 rather than 10.0. When I analyzed I found the article link and trying to fix this issue.